# Specifying a custom user model in django and calling an object

Tags: django

Alright, so I'm a bit stuck here. I decided to create my own user model, which is turning out to be a huge head ache. And not to mention this is my first django project from scratch...

So I am creating a dating app. I have a sample project of which I want to use some code and bring it over and adapt it to my project. I'm really not sure how to go about adapting some of the changes I need for my custom model. Here is the error I am getting:

```
NameError at /mingle/
name 'models' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/mingle/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'models' is not defined
Exception Location: /Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp/dating_app/views.py in mingle, line 113
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/papichulo/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Apr 2020 00:15:57 +0000
```

**SAMPLE code**

```
try:
        user = (User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        user = None
    print(User.username)
    try:
        bio = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).bio
    except models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        create = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    friend = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).friends.all()
    context = dict(user = user, friend = friend)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**My views.py**

```
def mingle(request):

    try:
        user = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        user = None
    print(User.username)
    try:
        description = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description
    except models.Profile.DoesNotExist:
        create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    match = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).matches.all()
    context = dict(user = user, match = match)  
    return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)
```

**my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings



class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not totally understand which part of the code you want to adapt or directly put into your project, however changing user model is not the best practice in my opinion.Please just improve and expand it with 'PROFILE' future. You can find a really usefull explanation in Vitor's forum.

Link: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Also you are not able to import Django Models in your models.py, I think your file locations are wrong. It must be like this;

```
├── example_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
|   └── pages
|      ├── __init__.py
│      ├── admin.py
│      ├── apps.py
│      ├── models.py
│      ├── tests.py
│      └── views.py
|      ├── templates
|          ├── pages
|              ├── home.html
└── manage.py
```

You can also check this link for details: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/template-structure